# Android Httpclient execute causes no peer certificate error

Tags: android, http, httpclient, execute

I have android app which acts as a client, and java project which is the server. the server has DB functions which I checked that they all work (I checked with postman).

however, when I run my app from a device, and tries to execute the http request, it drops this exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate.

I really don't understand what causes this problem, and any search in the questions didn't help me.

I use GET and POST requests. my server is the Heuroku free-server (I don't think that the problem is related to it, because it works on postman).

Here is the problematic code:

```
private String GET(String url){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            }
            else {
                result = "Did not work!";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String POST(String url, String jsonParamsAsString) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url);
            StringEntity input = new StringEntity(jsonParamsAsString);
            //input.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8" );
            input.setContentType("application/json");
            postRequest.setEntity(input);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            result = convertInputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
           // byte  ptext[] = result.getBytes();
           // result = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I personally hate the default api. I use okhttp https://github.com/square/okhttp

Comment: are you sure is http and not https?

Comment: you are right! I used https connection in my url. I changed to http:\\.. and now it works! thank you very much!